How can I increment a given number from a cell x amount of times. x taken from another cell?
I have a sheet of data and I need to take a given number from a cell

for example, 100022828312 from A1942 and then increment this number 4 times. number 4 is take from cell D1942.
And I have to do it for every number given in the A column.
I tried using Sequence and rpt and bunch of other stuff I googled, but unfortunately couldn't figure out how to do it exactly.
So I have this formula
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE('Sheet1'!D1942;1;'Sheet1'!A1942;1))

But it only works for just 1 cell and I need for it to work for all the numbers in the A column. Please help
Tried googling formulas and found one but still not the exact solution

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

the reason we ask for an example of the desired result, is there are often many ways to interpret a question. In any event, how about this is cell F1 (set the length of the range for column a & D to suit) =map(A1:A13,D1:D13,lambda(val,increment,sequence(1,increment,val+1,1))).

100022828312 is located at cell A1942, and 4 is from cell D1942. in which cell does the result goes?
